# Theorem about the cardinality of a finite field (mod(p))

Tags: linear-algebra

In Linear Algebra 1, our professor provided the following theorem:

> Let $\Bbb F$ be a finite field. Therefore, there exists some prime number p, and n $\ge$ 1  S.T |$\mathbb F$|= $p^n$.

The proof is left as an exercise to the reader.
I know that z/p is a field $\iff p$ is prime, but how does that fact help me prove the theorem? I am stumped.

Comment: What have you tried? Alternatively, what is the context behind this problem; where did you find it, and what relevant knowledge do you have?

Comment: Hint: let us write $\;\Bbb F_p:=\Bbb Z/p\;$ for the prime (minimal, if you want) field of characteristic $\;p\;$ . Then any other field $\;\Bbb F\;$ containing this field (i.e., any field of characteristic $\;p$) is a linear space over $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ . If $\;\dim_{\Bbb F_p}\Bbb F=n\;$ , then it is a basic exercise in basic linear algebra to show that $\;|\Bbb F|=p^n\;$ . Work on this

Comment: @DonAntonio Showing that |$\mathbb F$|= $p^n$ seems now like more of a counting problem than a linear algebra one?

Comment: @Noam Well, yes...but you must know the basic linear algebra about unique expression of any vector as linear combination of a basis . It still requires algebra.